# Getting selected row from a button in a view based tableview

Tags: cocoa, core-data, tableview, nsarraycontroller, target-action

I have a view based tableview with a button which displays a popover:

[image]

How would I go about setting the selected to the row that holds the pressed button.

I'm using core data, with an array controller.  I plan to have the tableview in the popover show related objects.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a tag equal to row to every cell button, `button.tag = indexPath.row;`
Then in your button's `selector` you just call

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0]];
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that everything is hooked up through bindings.  I'm guessing you mean set up the button tag in tableView:rowForView:. I'll try subclassing the tableRowView and setting it up there.

Comment: You've got to do that in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: